# What would be the proper adjective to describe an 'open' padlock?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, cultural-correctness

I'm trying to describe an 'open' padlock hanging from a latch.
['open', so a character can lock someone else in the following paragraph]

Is 'open' the right term?

I've also seen 'unsecured', 'unlocked', and 'free', but I'm not sure which term is of common use in American English.

Comment: "Open" is a reasonable term.

Comment: 'Free' isn't used for locks, but it might be for a lockable cubicle, or a public locker (i.e. the thing that can be locked).

Comment: @WeatherVane "free" as in "available" rather than "open" ?  A "free padlock" would be one that doesn't cost anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *open* lock is what you want. That is what the next character will need if they are to *fasten* the lock shut later.

'Free' is not in common usage much in American English. Though 'unlocked' is a good description as many locks can be shut without being locked. These appear locked or latched but are *unsecured*. Your goal seems to be a lock that on sight is clearly open and unlocked.

Answer (score 2):

*Open* is the right term.

That said, if you wish to get really technical and pedantic and all, you might want to consider "unlatched."

As in:

An *unlatched* padlock hung by the shackle from the loop.